Помогите декомпилировать .exe файл на python
Недавно я захотел декомпилировать свою программу на pyinstaller. Я перепробовал и pydumpck, uncompyle6. Достал только .pyc файл, основной код pydumpck давать не хочет и в консоли высвечивается много ошибок Unknown type (какой то hex). .pyc файл не декомпилируется и пишет Unknown magic number 227 in main.pyc. Pycdc просто не хочет почему то загружать файл. Да и я не уверен что .pyc файл верный.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

На данный момент можно декомпилировать только Python 3.9 (если не ошибаюсь). Но и то, часть кода канет в лето, и придётся изрядно повозиться над восстановлением работоспособности того что получилось вытащить из .pyc

Эти 2 решения мной не проверялись, пишу как ответ потому, что форматирование коммента слишком примитивно:

PyInstaller Extractor (pyinstxtractor):
Скачайте и установите pyinstxtractor1.
Запустите скрипт, передав имя .exe файла в качестве аргумента:
python pyinstxtractor.py filename


После извлечения файлов .pyc, используйте декомпилятор Python, например, uncompyle6 (только для .pyc, созданных в Python не выше 3.8), или decompyle++, или pycdc, чтобы преобразовать .pyc файлы обратно в исходный код Python:

EXE2PY-Decompiler:
Скачайте и установите EXE2PY-Decompiler2.
Следуйте инструкциям в README для декомпиляции .exe файлов, созданных с помощью PyInstaller или py2exe.

https://github.com/extremecoders-re/pyinstxtractor
https://github.com/LookiMan/EXE2PY-Decompiler

Я же уже сказал, что uncompyle, decompyle, pycdc не помогают
